# Python - sys.path[0] not working when compiled

Tags: python, pyinstaller, sys

I use pyinstaller to compile my python file but instead of sys.argv[0] printing out my current directory it prints out a completely random directory in %appdata% why?

Here is my code:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[0])
```

Command ran:

```
pyinstaller.exe s.py --onefile
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\Zeref\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI5002\base_library.zip
```

Instead of:

```
C:\Users\Zeref\Desktop\compile\compiled
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
print(sys._MEIPASS)
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: This works sort of, but I need just the directory. This will include the directory and file name